# Filling a responsive div proportionately

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I am trying to code my first RWD site and I want to have a grid of images for my portfolio that scale responsively, but that also display the images in proportion and fill their parent div in each case.

Here's my HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="pixooma_boilerplate.css">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<div id="wrapper">
<div class="latest"><img src="gilhooley.jpg">
</div>
<div class="others portrait"><img src="points_kit_cover.jpg">
</div>
<div class="others landscape"><img src="finland_dps2.jpg">
</div>
<div class="others landscape"><img src="CS-logo-chosen.jpg">
</div>
<div class="others landscape"><img src="olympic.jpg.jpg">
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

and here's my CSS (excluding the HTML5 boilerplate styles):

```
body {
    background:#39C;
}

#wrapper {
    background:#993;
    width:90%;
    max-width:1200px;
    margin:0 auto;
}

img {
    max-width:100%;
}



.latest {
    width:50%;
    max-width:800px;
    max-height:600px;
    background-color:#669;
    float:left;
}

.others {
    width:25%;
    max-width:300px;
    max-height:300px;
    background-color:#0C3;
    float:left;
    overflow:hidden;
}


@media screen and (max-width:800px) {

    .latest {
        width:100%;
    }

    .others {
        width:25%;
    }

}


@media screen and (max-width:600px) {

    .latest {
        width:100%;
    }

    .others {
        width:50%;
    }

}

@media screen and (max-width:320px) {

    .latest {
        width:100%;
    }

    .others {
        width:100%;
    }

}
```

I want the site to be able to upload an image of any size and have it proportionately fill the div without any overflow or background showing. Ideally I'd like it to be centered as well, but that may have to wait...!

Thankyou

Comment: Have you tried using the background property of div tag?I don't know which version you are using but in html5 img tag allows width and height to be specified in pixels only while div can have height and width in percentage and also has a background property, hence usually this workaround satisfies me in most cases.

Comment: Wouldn't this mean that I would need to add any image to the CSS as a background image and also create a new CSS style for every Div? Semantically, I would assume it is better to have the images in the html?

Comment: You don't need to create a separate CSS for each div; you are already giving source to each img tag you are using in html, hence instead your source will go into the div tag instead of img with different attribute name, that's it.

Comment: Use `object-fit` and `object-position` properties.